# Scroll View content size in Universal app?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, scroll, scrollview, universal

I am not sure how to set different scroller size dimensions for a universal app.

I have the code below so far in the implementation file for iPhone dimensions, but not sure how to code for iPad scroller dimensions as well.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [super viewDidLoad];

[ScrollerInstructions setScrollEnabled:YES];
[ScrollerInstructions setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 2000)];

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this, so you can set the contenSize in dependency of the device:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // iPad contentSize
    [ScrollerInstructions setContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 3000)];
} else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568) {
    // iPhone 5/5s contenSize
    [ScrollerInstructions setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 2500)];
} else {
    // old iPhone contenSize
    [ScrollerInstructions setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 2000)];
}
```

a good way to use is, to set this as define in your .pch file like this:

```
#define IS_IPAD ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE5 (!IS_IPAD && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >= 568))
```

this way you can use in your source simply:

```
if (IS_PAD) {

} else if (IS_IPHONE5) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot to ask about iphone5 and how the above would differ.

Comment: Thank you again so much thorb!